# Erlang Syntax error before function name in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, erlang

I am running my erlang scripts on eclipse, but I am having some problems in my script. My script is like this:

```
-module(test).
-export([Xf/1]).

Xf = fun(X) -> X + 3 end.
```

When I compile this script file, it says `syntax error before: Xf`. The function can run in erlang shell, but I really don't know why this problem happens in eclipse. Can anyone help me wit that?

Answer (score 4):

In the shell, it isn't defining a function, it's creating a new variable and assigning an anonymous function to it. You can't have top-level variables in Erlang modules, and you can't export variables. To make it a function, write

```
xf(X) -> X + 3.
```

Comment: Isn't creating a new variable and assigning an anonymous function to it the same as defining a function with the name of that variable?

Comment: It's equivalent in most ways, but not exactly the same. For one, in Erlang you _can't_ define a function with the name of a variable: function names start with lower-case letters (or surrounded in backquotes), variable names with upper-case. They can be defined in different circumstances (as this question shows), etc.